# Facebook friends invite - Changing link of Skip button for friends invite?

Tags: facebook

Can you please tell me how can I change the link of Skip button as shown in the screenshot below ?

[image: link]

Comment: how can u change the skip link of facebook?...you can use the invite friends feature in ur app

Comment: What is this dialog? Is this the old invite dialog? Why aren't you using the new one? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/